# MYSQL subquery returns an error due to alias

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to use a subquery to get the latitude with the lowest number from my database with a limit to display 2 rows (ORDER BY lat ASC LIMIT 2) and also select all return row and randomize it with ORDER BY rand(), I tried to use alias as t1 but returned an error: "Duplicate column name 'title'". Please help me point where I got it wrong. Below is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT hobber_deal_page.id,hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,hobber_deal_page.category_id,
hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,hobber_deal_page.title,hobber_deal_page.title,
hobber_deal_page.description,hobber_deal_page.emirate,hobber_deal_page.lat,
hobber_deal_page.lng,hobber_deal_page.address,hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
hobber_deal_page.price,hobber_deal_page.created_at, 
AVG(hobber_ratings.ratings) AS ratings 
FROM hobber_deal_page 
LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id 
GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id 
ORDER BY lat ASC LIMIT 2) t1 
ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: Which error do you get exactly? Please show us the entire error message.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ERROR: Duplicate column name 'title'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have detected a failure in the GROUP BY clause. For this to work, the query should be as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
        SELECT hobber_deal_page.id,
            hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
            hobber_deal_page.category_id,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
            hobber_deal_page.title,
            hobber_deal_page.description,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate,
            hobber_deal_page.lat,
            hobber_deal_page.lng,
            hobber_deal_page.address,
            hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            hobber_deal_page.price,
            hobber_deal_page.created_at,
            AVG(hobber_ratings.ratings) AS ratings
        FROM hobber_deal_page
            LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id
        GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id,
            hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
            hobber_deal_page.category_id,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
            hobber_deal_page.title,
            hobber_deal_page.description,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate,
            hobber_deal_page.lat,
            hobber_deal_page.lng,
            hobber_deal_page.address,
            hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            hobber_deal_page.price,
            hobber_deal_page.created_at
        ORDER BY hobber_deal_page.lat ASC
        LIMIT 2
    ) t1
ORDER BY rand()
```

If you had put in the mistake you got, I could be more helpful.

*How do I add a query to display the rest of the row on the table excluding the ones display with the above query? i.e aside the row display with the LIMIT 2. For example let say the table is from 1 to 10 and the above query is able to display just 3 and 4, how do I display the rest 1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10 below 3 and 4.*

You can make and `UNION` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)) with the previous data and to avoid the duplicate data use the `DISTINCT` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)) clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
        SELECT hobber_deal_page.id,
            hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
            hobber_deal_page.category_id,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
            hobber_deal_page.title,
            hobber_deal_page.description,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate,
            hobber_deal_page.lat,
            hobber_deal_page.lng,
            hobber_deal_page.address,
            hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            hobber_deal_page.price,
            hobber_deal_page.created_at,
            AVG(hobber_ratings.ratings) AS ratings
        FROM hobber_deal_page
            LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id
        GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id,
            hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
            hobber_deal_page.category_id,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
            hobber_deal_page.title,
            hobber_deal_page.description,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate,
            hobber_deal_page.lat,
            hobber_deal_page.lng,
            hobber_deal_page.address,
            hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            hobber_deal_page.price,
            hobber_deal_page.created_at
        ORDER BY hobber_deal_page.lat ASC
        LIMIT 2
    ) t1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT *
FROM(
        SELECT hobber_deal_page.id,
            hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
            hobber_deal_page.category_id,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
            hobber_deal_page.title,
            hobber_deal_page.description,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate,
            hobber_deal_page.lat,
            hobber_deal_page.lng,
            hobber_deal_page.address,
            hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            hobber_deal_page.price,
            hobber_deal_page.created_at,
            AVG(hobber_ratings.ratings) AS ratings
        FROM hobber_deal_page
            LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id
        GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id,
            hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
            hobber_deal_page.category_id,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
            hobber_deal_page.title,
            hobber_deal_page.description,
            hobber_deal_page.emirate,
            hobber_deal_page.lat,
            hobber_deal_page.lng,
            hobber_deal_page.address,
            hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            hobber_deal_page.price,
            hobber_deal_page.created_at
        ORDER BY hobber_deal_page.lat ASC
    ) t2
```

Comment: When I tried your query I got an error saying "Duplicate column name 'title'"

Comment: Corrected! The column  hobber_deal_page.title was duplicated. Thank you!

Comment: How do I add a query to display the rest of the row on the table excluding the ones display with the above query? i.e aside the row display with the LIMIT 2. For example let say the table is from 1 to 10 and the above query is able to display just 3 and 4, how do I display the rest 1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10 below 3 and 4.

Comment: You can use an UNION with the data and use the DISTINCT clause. See my extended response.

Comment: The new query returns an error: "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: Try now. I hope that now the query is correct.

Comment: It is not randomizing again, there is no rand() in your query. I want the first LIMIT 2 to randomize.